# Class 'App\Models\X' not found - after moving models to a folder

Tags: php

I moved my models from `app\` to `app\Models`,
then I also changed the use paths in the controllers:

**Before:**

```
use App\Project;
```

**After:**

```
use App\Models\Project;
```

It should work, but now I get `Class 'App\Models\X' not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you changed namespace in all modals like modal is User.php

namespace App\Models\Project;

Comment: add namespace app/models in your model and run composer dump-autoload. it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving to a different folder isnt the only thing you need to do. You need to change the namespace as well

So, in your model, add the following

`namespace App\Models;`